# How to Find HTML-Encoded Character in JavaScript String?

Tags: javascript, html

How would you go about finding a string constant that is not HTML-safe?

It appears the following searches for the individual characters.

```
var i = text.indexOf('&raquo;')
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of a non-safe string constant?

Comment: @Jcubed: My question includes an example of the type of character I had in mind. At any rate, the question has been asked and answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var i = text.indexOf('\273')
```

would search for the actual character.

http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/special_characters.htm explains how to escape special characters in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You'll first need to unescape the HTML in the pattern:

```
var i = text.indexOf(decodeHTML('&raquo;'));

function decodeHTML(s) { // e.g. using jQuery
    return $('<div>' + s + '</div>').text();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the html directly.

`document.getElementById('search').innerHTML.indexOf('&raquo;')`

Comment: It's not able to find that. The data is updated via AJAX. Perhaps the HTML contains the character directory without using `&raquo;`?